# Is it possible to call ACPI methods from C + + programs?

Tags: c#, c++, driver, acpi

I hope to call ACPI methods through C++ library in C#, cause I am writing a uwp app for an OEM company, They provide an ACPI method to control the power supply of a USB device. but I seem to find in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e51049a6-2b86-48be-94a8-36032de88c1e/is-it-possible-to-call-acpi-control-methods-from-a-c-program?forum=wdk) that ACPI methods cannot be called in C++ library(Correct it, I now know it's completely right).

It says: "ACPI methods can only be called from a kernel driver, and then only from the driver stack for the device that the method is declared in the DSDT.”

In addition, i seem to have found some repositories that can call ACPI methods in C# (user mode), such as [AcpiTool](https://github.com/DOGSHITD/AcpiTool) and [WindowsHwAccess](https://github.com/kdshk/WindowsHwAccess)(seem to require running in kernel mode, I'm not sure).

**Anyway, can I call APCI methods in C#(user mode) through the C++ library imported into the C# project? Or should i say that the C++ library introduced in the C# project can run in kernel mode?**

Comment: What is confusing? the info is very clear, "ACPI methods can only be called from a kernel driver". If you aren't at kernel level then you can't call it. And even if you are at kernel level, then your library must be part of the driver stack declared in the DSDT.

Comment: If you don't understand the passage you are quoting, take it to mean "No, you can't do that". And by *"you"* I mean someone who can't understand that passage. If you don't own a pair of kernel-colored glasses, stay away from the kernel (unless your favorite color is blue)

Comment: Thanks reply, i'm very sorry, It's really not clear, I have reedit the question.

Comment: ACPI code requires ACPI interpreter to handle it. Under OS usually this interpreter is a part of its kernel (this is the case for at least Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD). So, for the ACPICA (one of the interpreter implementations) it's probably possible in debug mode, if it's allowed by the OS kernel.

Comment: Finally, I suggest that they provide me with WMI interface, and thank you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s of course possible to call ACPI from C++ if you run said C++ in kernel context or on bare metal (when your code runs directly on the hardware without an operating system as an intermediary). And you certainly could stick a C# runtime into kernel context and thus call ACPI from C#. It has been done: read up on Project Midori, where Windows got reimplemented entirely in managed code. But you’re asking whether you can call ACPI from your C# userland code on Windows. You can’t do it directly but there may be drivers bundled with Windows that expose the information and/or functionality that you’re after. You have a typical XY problem: you think you need ACPI but you didn’t say what for. It’s highly likely that the “what for” part has an answer that doesn’t necessitate writing driver code nor doing direct ACPI calls. Please update your question with a description of what is it that you’re trying to do - forget about ACPI for the time being. If ACPI turns out to be the only way to do it, so be it, but let someone state that in an answer instead of you just going with that assumption.

TL;DR: You’re probably going about it in a too complicated fashion.

Comment: “ where Windows got reimplemented entirely in managed code” - Midori was a research kernel, it wasn’t “Windows” and it didn’t have a userland API resembling Win32 at all. The builds I played with at Microsoft in 2014 didn’t have a GUI or window manager at all, it was all text-mode.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica Thank you very much for your reply. Your answer contains almost everything I want to know. I am writing uwp app for an OEM company. They only provide me with an ACPI method. I need to call that method to power a USB device. As you said, I may not use overly complex solutions (such as project Midori), but so far, I still don't know what I should do. Maybe I am too stupid? I don't know if there's drivers for me to do it.

Comment: @Dai I guess I went a bit ahead of myself, but there was a bit more to it than just "text mode" - and userland would have been totally different as the whole idea was that nothing blocked, not even the paging system, and all those legacy APIs are just a mess of blocking calls. They had the multimedia subsystem going, so I bet there was a functional display system. But I don't have insider info.

Comment: "Power a USB device"? What does that mean? Is that device something you'd plug into a regular PC? In such case, there's nothing you need from ACPI directly. The USB subsystem in Windows is all you need, and power management for USB devices IIRC works just fine using the user mode driver model, so you can do it all without even knowing what ACPI is. I think they may not be quite on top of what's what, unless their device is something special that's not USB compliant per se, e.g. a motherboard device that has power delivery controlled by mechanisms outside of normal USB root hub control.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica The "nothing blocks" concept comes from Dave Cutler who is the main designer behind VMS and then NT, I understand Midori was also based around the same idea. In Windows 10 today, the C-style synchronous IO functions in Win32 abstract-away the real asynchronous non-blocking IO functionality in NT.

Comment: @Victor "I am writing uwp app for an OEM company." - _have fun with that_ - UWP applications on Windows are sandboxed and require you to use external broker-processes to do anything interesting with hardware or other OS components - this has the side-effect of making UWP about as attractive as using Electron (as realistically, both platforms require external helper processes in this regard). Personally I'd skip UWP and go back to WPF, at least that way you can have users easily run your program with elevated permissions and keep everything in-proc.

Comment: @Dai To the best of my knowledge there's no async filesystem access anywhere in modern Windows, at any level, and there's a lot of fundamental blocking-only stuff deep inside. Like... paging itself (even though technically you could be brave and completely disable all demand paging). That's one reason why Midori couldn't have been a partial job. It's a similar story in Linux: access to block devices can be async, as long as there's no filesystem involved. As soon as the block device is file-mapped (i.e. an image), there's no non-blocking access, and so it is on Windows AFAIK.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica "To the best of my knowledge there's no async filesystem access anywhere in modern Windows" - asynchronous IO is the basis for Win32's Overlapped IO system. There's a whole article on MS docs about Windows' async IO features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o - it's the basis for `System.IO.FileSteam`'s async support (albeit in .NET Framework and .NET Core it requires explicit opt-in with a special constructor call).

Comment: @ReinstateMonica The article I linked to suggests that "overlapped IO" and "async IO" are synonymous - they are, but it's more like "overlapped IO" is a special-case of asynchronous IO in that (I believe) you can have multiple async IO operations pending for the same file-handle rather than having to await each one in-turn - it's powerful, but also very difficult to program correctly: the performance advantages only make sense when an application does crazy amounts of IO, like a database server.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica This is a special case. The USB device is directly connected to the motherboard and cannot be plugged in or unplugged, but it is also a standard USB device. I hope this is not the key to the problem. And I use the desktop bridge, which is converted from WPF to uwp, so I don't need to worry about permissions.

Comment: @Dai I know about the synonyms, but this support is absolutely non-dependable. If you have the typical encrypted and/or compressed files in an enterprise environment, asynchronous access is not possible. So it's really a special-case-only sort of an API and you can't actually depend on its non-blocking aspects in general. I've been writing async-only code for decades now so I know how bad it is on Windows. When I use Linux, I end up doing all disk-based filesystem access with filesystem drivers in userspace, so that it can be all async, still with some caveats.

Comment: Finally, I suggest that they provide me with WMI interface, and thank you guys.